# Batch modify file name prefixes using batch scripts in Windows

Tags: batch-file

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "OLD_PREFIX="
set /p "OLD_PREFIX=Enter the old prefix: "

set "NEW_PREFIX="
set /p "NEW_PREFIX=Enter the new prefix: "

set found_files=0
set found_dirs=0

for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d %OLD_PREFIX%*') do (
    set "FILENAME=%%F"
    if "!FILENAME:~0,^%OLD_PREFIX:^=^%!=="%OLD_PREFIX%" (
        set "NEW_FILENAME=%NEW_PREFIX%!FILENAME:~%OLD_PREFIX:~0,-1%!"
        ren "%%F" "!NEW_FILENAME!"
        set /a found_files+=1
    )
)

for /d %%D in (%OLD_PREFIX%*) do (
    set "DIRNAME=%%D"
    if "!DIRNAME:~0,^%OLD_PREFIX:^=^%!=="%OLD_PREFIX%" (
        set "NEW_DIRNAME=%NEW_PREFIX%!DIRNAME:~%OLD_PREFIX:~0,-1%!"
        ren "%%D" "!NEW_DIRNAME!"
        set /a found_dirs+=1
    )
)

echo %found_files% file(s) renamed.
echo %found_dirs% directory(ies) renamed.

pause
```

This script will first prompt the user to input an old prefix and a new prefix, and then use the dir command to list all files and folders that start with the old prefix. In the for loop, it first checks whether the current file or folder name starts with the old prefix. If so, it modifies the name by adding the new prefix in front and removing the character of the old prefix from the original name, so that the middle part remains unchanged.

For example, if the old prefix is "abc" and the new prefix is "xyz", and the file name is "abcdeabc.txt", then the modified file name will be "xyzdeabc.txt". If the file name does not start with the old prefix, it will not be modified.

However, when I ran the script, it did not modify any file names and exited directly. I am not sure what went wrong, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"

:: use fixed values for old/new prefix

SET "old_prefix=sub"
SET "new_prefix=sub-q-"

SET /a found_files=0
SET /a found_dirs=0

FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,1000) DO (
 IF "!old_prefix:~%%e,1!" neq "" SET /a old_length=%%e+1
)

FOR %%y IN (-d d) DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('dir /b /a%%y "%sourcedir%\%old_prefix%*"') DO (
  SET "oldname=%%e"
  IF /I "!oldname:~0,%old_length%!"=="%old_prefix%" (
   ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\!oldname!" "%new_prefix%!oldname:~%old_length%!"
   IF "%%y"=="d" (SET /a found_dirs+=1) ELSE (SET /a found_files+=1)
  )
 )
)

SET found

GOTO :EOF
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Your problem is that `"!FILENAME:~0,^%OLD_PREFIX:^=^%!` is invalid; the second parameter in such a string-substitution must be resolved to a numeric value (the length of the substring selected in this case).

So - calculate the length of the old prefix, noting that this value is both the length of the prefix and the start-point for the "remainder of the name" substring of the old prefix.

`%%y` is set to `-d` and `d` to modify the attributes selected for the `dir` command. Read each file/directory name into `%%e`, check that the prefix is as selected (which should never fail as the prefix is pre-filtered by the `dir`) - note the `/i` to force case-insensitive. Then apply the `ren` and switch the counter depending on the value of `%%y`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. I greatly appreciate your corrections, and I have revised my script accordingly to ensure accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method. The main differences being that, I use only one `For` loop, do not attempt to rename, if an existing file or directory already exists, and only increment the counter when a rename was successful, (as opposed to counting all files and directories matching the prefix):

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "OLD_PREFIX="
Set /P "OLD_PREFIX=Enter the old prefix>"

Set "NEW_PREFIX="
Set /P "NEW_PREFIX=Enter the new prefix>"

Set /A RENAMED_FILES=RENAMED_DIRS=0

For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir "%OLD_PREFIX%*" /A /B 2^>NUL') Do (
    Set "OBJ_NAME=%%G" & Set "OBJ_TYPE=%%~aG" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If "!OBJ_TYPE:~,1!" == "d" (
        If Not Exist "%NEW_PREFIX%!OBJ_NAME:*%OLD_PREFIX%=!\." (
            Ren "%%G" "%NEW_PREFIX%!OBJ_NAME:*%OLD_PREFIX%=!" 2>NUL
            If ErrorLevel 1 (EndLocal) Else EndLocal & Set /A RENAMED_DIRS += 1)
    ) Else If Not Exist "%NEW_PREFIX%!OBJ_NAME:*%OLD_PREFIX%=!" (
        Ren "%%G" "%NEW_PREFIX%!OBJ_NAME:*%OLD_PREFIX%=!" 2>NUL
        If ErrorLevel 1 (EndLocal) Else EndLocal & Set /A RENAMED_FILES += 1))

Echo %RENAMED_FILES% file(s) renamed.
Echo %RENAMED_DIRS% directory(ies) renamed.

Pause
```

As a side note: You really should be careful using the `Set` command with the `/P` option for requesting user input, *(in this case more especially with the second prompt)*. The end user could input anything at all here, including characters which are disallowed in Windows file and directory naming. A robust script would parse their input, and re-prompt should any of those characters be present.